# How do I use laravel eloquent for this relationship query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

November 27, 2017 7:24 AM:
**Update**: Have a slight requirement change and need some help with that too:
[How to write this query in laravel query builder or eloquent or sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502101/how-to-write-this-query-in-laravel-query-builder-or-eloquent-or-sql)

Leaving this question here for reference.
Thanks for the answers.

---

I have a many-to-many relationships between campaigns and users.

**Campagin.php**

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function campaigns()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Campaign');
}
```

I have a pivot table for this relatioship: `campaign_user`, which has only 2 columns `campaign_id` and `user_id`.

Next, I have one-to-many relationships between campaign and marker.
1 campaign has many markers

**Campaign.php**

```
public function markers()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Marker', 'campaign_id');
}
```

**Marker.php**

```
public function campaign()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaign', 'campaign_id');
}
```

Now in this url `/campaign/2/marker`, I want to get all markers that is under campaign 2 that belongs to the current user.

How do I use eloquent to achieve this?

In SQL its roughly like this:

```sql
select * from markers where campaign_id in (select campaign_id from campaigns 
left join campaign_user on (campaigns.id = campaign_user.campaign_id)
where campaign_user.campaign_id = 2 and campaign_user.user_id = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check for the campaign `exists` or not under your `current` user.

```
$campaign = Campaign::where('id','=',$campaign_id)->whereHas('users',function($q){
        $q->where('id','=',$user_id);
    })->first();
```

Then fetch all the `Marker` with `Campaign`-

```
    if($campaign!=null){
        Marker::where('campaign_id','=',$campaign->id)->with('campaign')->get();
    }
```

Comment: Where in the code is "$campaign = Campaign::..." used? Ina controller? In a view?

Comment: @GreatDayDan probably in controller but you can use anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `whereHas()` like this:

```
Marker::whereHas('campaign', function($q) use ($campaignId) {
    $q->where('id', $campaignId)
      ->whereHas('users', function($q) {
          $q->where('id', auth()->id());
      });
})->get();
```